# Three js - Different shadow maps for different lights

Tags: optimization, three.js, shadow, shadow-mapping

I have a three js scene with two lights. I want light A to use PCFShadowMap and light B to use BasicShadowMap. How to achieve that?

My main concern is performance. I am looking for a way to cast different quality shadows from different light sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want light A to use PCFShadowMap and light B to use BasicShadowMap. How to achieve that?

This is not possible. The type of shadow maps can only be configured globally on renderer level:

```js
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
```

If you are concerned about performance, consider to lower the resolution of shadow maps which you can configure per light.

```
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 256;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 256;
```